# Turn off CSS property

Tags: css, overriding

Lets say I have a plugin's CSS which loads later as my style.css

```
/*style.css*/
.something {
position:absolute;
left: 0px !important;                       
}

/*plugin's CSS*/
.something {
position:absolute;
left: -50px;                       
}
```

/*now it has 0px but i want no left value at all*/

i know i can set !important so that property wont be overriden, but is there any solution to turn "left" off as Chrome DevTools uncheck a property?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I am aware (someone please feel free to correct me) there is no way to directly "turn off" a CSS property like in the Chrome DevTools.

The closest you can get it to reset the property to its default. In your example, it would be  "left:auto;"

P.S. You may wish to adjust your tags to get more views and hopefully answers.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the "auto" value for left:

```
.something
{
    position:absolute;
    left:auto !important;
}
```

"auto" will reset to the default (that is set by browsers for that style)

more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

Comment: lol i already found it. If i took the time to google it properly instead of writing this question...

Answer (score 1):

Specificity is the key to selecting the CSS attribute that you really want.  Leverage the specific structure of the HTML in the plugin vs. non-plugin case so that specificity rules select the CSS you desire when plugin rules should apply.

There's a great overview of specificity here:

[image]

Source: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

One thought that comes to mind is to use an additional class, *plugin*, along with an appropriate selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to override it then you can play with [CSS Specificity Rules](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)