# Disable a CSS rule

Tags: css, content-management-system

Here is my problem :
I use a CMS with a default CSS file that I don't want to modify because the CMS updates could replace this file. So I use a custom CSS file in addition of the default CSS file to change the CMS theme.
But sometimes I just want to disable a rule written in the default CSS file. As I can't delete or comment the rule, I re-write the same rule in the custom CSS file with the default values in the properties.

**Example :**

```
/* default CSS file */
.class { background-color : black; }

/* cutom CSS file */
.class { background-color : none; }
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to just disable a rule without re-writting the same rule ?

Comment: Why don't just not include this file in your page and include your custom one?

Comment: @pankar The 2 files are included in the pages. The custom one disable the CSS rules of the default one by re-writting them.

Comment: What @pankar meant was, if you don't want to edit the default, then either delete the call to the stylesheet or comment it out. You can copy and paste everything from it (if it includes styles you need) and  only edit your new custom css. Custom will have all the edits. Commented out will have the old default.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the clarification. Firstly i can't delete the call to the stylesheet or comment it out, for the same reason I can't modify the default CSS file : updates. Then you suggest me to make an complete copy of the default CSS file into the custom CSS file and then modify the rules I want? So it's the same solution as re-writting rules?

Comment: @Nicolas - My suggestion of copy/pasting was only IF you needed some of the styles from the default. And I assumed since you could add a custom stylesheet to the page, you could also remove the original. I guess I'm confused what updates will replace that file - and if it's commented out or deleted from your <head> - won't it update the css file - but it won't matter since you aren't using it?  (Sorry, guess I'm confused on 100% what the problem is with why you can't do that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off CSS property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939519/turn-off-css-property)

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your help. To clarify a bit the update issue : the CMS updates could replace any default file of CMS like the default CSS file or the PHP file that includes the CSS in the <head>. So I shouldn't modify these files, and I can only modify the custom files like CSS or JS that will added after the default CSS and JS of the CMS.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela - Not really the same problem. And the solution of the other topic is to re-write the rule with the default values in the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think...basically no. You have to specify exactly same rules which you would like to disable.

But you can add some postprocessor to css files. In apache, all css requests route to something like postprocessor.php and there you can remove code which don't want with some parser, replacer.

Second choice is make some plugin for cms, which have some settings for this.

Third way to do this is using some dynamic/meta/scripting css language etc. SASS, LESS for generating this disabling rules.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will take a look at LESS to see if something match my needs.

Comment: Unfortunately LESS is just a way to write css rules more efficiently. As you wrote, the only way to deactivate a css rule is to rewrite it with the default values.