# `Cross` css property like in Chrome dev tools w/ custom css or js script?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a webite, and I installed a heatmap tool in it.

### Problem

The heatmap tool has some overwriting css class that will change the layout of the whole page.

### Solution

If I cross the css class in chrome dev tool, the page look fine again. Like this

[image]

And I certainly can't edit the css source code for the heatmap tool.

### My question

I don't want to manually uncheck the css class everytime I use this tool. Is there anyway to automatically override or disable it? Like using some custom css or js script w/ some chrome extentions.

However, I find in [Turn off CSS property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939519/turn-off-css-property/11939642) there seems no good solution yet?

Comment: Apply `!important` to your CSS properties

Comment: why to use same class name?

Comment: This is CSS specificity in action. Read about [The CSS Cascade](https://wattenberger.com/blog/css-cascade) to understand what's going on. And don't slap on `!Important` without understanding why you are having an issue.